# Munin graph is incomplete with Tomcat Threads plugin

Tags: munin, tomcat9

I have munin running rather fine on a CentOs webserver machine, except for one graph from the "Tomcat Threads" plugin that is incomplete.
Why is it doing this? My server is far from overloaded.

See the incomplete graph :

[image: Munin graph incomplete]

All other Tomcat graphs are ok, like this one : 
[image: Munin graph ok]

When I run the following command :

```
 munin-run tomcat_threads
```

It will fail most of the time, giving me the same answer :

```
busy.value U
idle.value U
```

Sometimes it will work, giving me correct values :

```
busy.value 1
idle.value 9
```

Debug mode and log don't show any useful information.

I am running

- CentOS 7.7.1908
- Apache 2.4.6
- Tomcat 9.0.16
- Munin-Node 2.0.51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert but maybe there's a typo in tomcat_threads plugin code.
I replaced '&&' with '||' in the following sentence and everything worked like a charm:

```
if($xml->{'connector'}->{$CONNECTOR}->{'threadInfo'}->[0]->{'currentThreadsBusy'} &&
    $xml->{'connector'}->{$CONNECTOR}->{'threadInfo'}->[0]->{'currentThreadCount'}) {
    print "busy.value " . $xml->{'connector'}->{$CONNECTOR}->{'threadInfo'}->[0]->{'currentThreadsBusy'} . "\n";
    print "idle.value " .
          ($xml->{'connector'}->{$CONNECTOR}->{'threadInfo'}->[0]->{'currentThreadCount'} -
          $xml->{'connector'}->{$CONNECTOR}->{'threadInfo'}->[0]->{'currentThreadsBusy'}) . "\n";
} else {
    print "busy.value U\n";
    print "idle.value U\n";
}
```

Comment: The fix has been merged : https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/commit/ebcbf2483aac9ae1a3c6303ca6235d1748f7033c